# How To Count Unique Values Based On Another Columns cell value being between times

Tags: count, duplicates, between, sumifs, unique-values

I am pulling my hair out on what I thought would be a simple formula.

I am wanting to figure out how many customers I have, qty of items sold and $ between the different times of the day.

For Cust# i have been trying to use the following (changing the time);

=SUM(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10000,$A$2:$A$10000)=1,0),COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$10000,">8.00",$C$2:$C$10000,"<8.59"))

For QTY: =SUMIFS(D2:D10000,$C$2:$C$10000,">8.00",$C$2:$C$10000,"<8.59")

For Sales:=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$10000,$C$2:$C$10000,">8.00",$C$2:$C$10000,"<8.59")

Attached is a snapshot of the first few rows of my data.

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG!!

Thanks so[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFRUv.png)ooo much in advance for your help